# How to soup a browser response

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I've got a program that sends a lot of requests to a website using RoboBrowser and gets the answers, but now I need to filter these answers to only the ones that don't have this string " Case Status Not Available " I tried to use beautifulsoup for it, but it is returning an error.

Here's the code so far:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import pickle
import requests
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs")
    print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print('Current working directory is '+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs')
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, " "))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()

def run(command):
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        args = shlex.split(command)
    else:
        args = command
    s = subprocess.Popen(args,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = s.communicate()
    return s.returncode == 0, output, errors

# Change this to your PDF file base directory
base_directory = 'C:\\PROJECT\\pdfs'
if not os.path.isdir(base_directory):
    print "%s is not a directory" % base_directory
    exit(1)
# Change this to your pdf2htmlEX executable location
bin_path = 'C:\\Python27\\pdfminer-20140328\\tools\\pdf2txt.py'
if not os.path.isfile(bin_path):
    print "Could not find %s" % bin_path
    exit(1)
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a PDF file
        if not file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        # Convert your PDF to HTML here
        args = (bin_path, file_name, file_path)
        success, output, errors = run("python %s -o %s.html %s " %args)
        if not success:
            print "Could not convert %s to HTML" % file_path
            print "%s" % errors
htmls_path = 'C:\\PROJECT'
with open ('score.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(htmls_path):
        for file_name in file_name_list:
            if not file_name.endswith('.html'):
                continue
            with open(file_name) as markup:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
                text = soup.get_text()
                match = re.findall("PA/(\S*)", text)#To remove the names that appear, just remove the last (\S*), to add them is just add the (\S*), before it there was a \s*
                print(match)
                writer.writerow(match)
                for item in match:
                    data = item.split('/')
                    case_number = data[0]
                    case_year = data[1]

                    browser = RoboBrowser()
                    browser.open('http://www.pa.org.mt/page.aspx?n=63C70E73&CaseType=PA')
                    form = browser.get_forms()[0]  # Get the first form on the page
                    form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseNo'].value = case_number
                    form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$txtCaseYear'].value = case_year

                    browser.submit_form(form, submit=form['ctl00$PageContent$ContentControl$ctl00$btnSubmit'])

                    # Use BeautifulSoup to parse this data
                    print(browser.response.text)
                    souptwo = BeautifulSoup(browser.response.text)
                    texttwo = soup.get_text()
                    matchtwo = soup.findall('<td class="fieldData">Case Status Not Available</TD>')
                    if not matchtwo:
                        soupthree = BeautifulSoup(browser.response.text)
                        print soupthree
```

The error that returns is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROJECT\pdfs\converterpluspa.py", line 87, in <module>
    matchtwo = soup.findall('<td class="fieldData">Case Status Not Available</TD>')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 87 includes an attempt to call the method `findall` of `soup`. `soup` was defined in line 65 where `BeautifulSoup` was called to parse the contents of a file. Since the error diagnostic says that `soup` is None this means that `BeautifulSoup` was unable to parse that file.

Comment: Are you confident that the contents of the files you're giving to BeautifulSoup are valid HTML? You should arrange to print the first hundred  or so characters of them for your examination.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to rearrange the program and now it is almost workin, now I need to make a table out of the information I get from a lot of links like this http://www.pa.org.mt/SearchPA, I need to get the tables: Current aplication status and every table under it and write it to simple single excel table but I tried and what is getting is just a copy of the tables html

Comment: If you still need advice then you should submit a new question.